# Como envio dados de uma tabela HTML dinâmica via json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Preciso fazer algo parecido com o código abaixo:

Aqui crio a tabel htmla dinâmicamente:

```
$('#btnIncluirContato').on('click', function () {

    $('#tblContato tbody').append('<tr id=' + $('#ContatoID').val() + '>' +
    '<td class="NomeContato" id="NomeContato">' + $('#NomeContato').val() + '</td>' +
    '<td class="TelefoneContato" id="TelefoneContato">' + $('#TelefoneContato').val() + '</td>' +
     '<td class="remover" id="remover">' + '<a href="#"><img src="/Content/Images/excluirFlatRed.png" class="remover" /></a>' + '</td>' +
    '</tr>');

});
```

Aqui envio para o Banco de dados via ajax:

```
 $("#btnFinalizar").click(function () {

    //Percorrer a tabela 
    var table = $('#tblContato');
    table.find('tr').each(function (indice) {

        $(this).find('td').each(function (indice) {

        });

    });

    //Setar campos inputs da Tela
    var _TBCliente = {
        'ID': $('#campoID').val(),
        'Nome': $('#campoNome').val(),
        'Idade': $('#campoIdade').val(),
        'TBContato':[]
    };

    //Adicionar os itens da Tabela de Contato
    _TBCliente.TBContato.push({

    });

    //Com o objeto populado eu vou enviar para o banco via $.ajax
});
```

A principal dúvida é como pegar os dados da tabela HTML e popular o objeto que será enviado para um méto JsonResult ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode tentar assim:

> ```
> var dados  =  [];
> var i     =  0;
> var table = $('#tblContato');
> table.find('tr').each(function () {
>    dados[i]['id']  =  $( this ).find( 'td:nth-child(1)' ).text();
>    dados[i]['nome']  =  $( this ).find( 'td:nth-child(2)' ).text();
>    dados[i]['idade']  =  $( this ).find( 'td:nth-child(3)' ).text();
>    dados[i]['contato']  =  $( this ).find( 'td:nth-child(4)' ).text();
>    i++;
> });
> ```

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {meusDados:dados},
   url: "http://seusite.com.br/processarPost",
   success: function( data ){
       alert( 'Enviou' )
   },
   error: function (request, status, error) {
      alert(request.responseText);
   }
});
```

Troque a pseudo-class nth-child para o seu caso.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: O pseudo-class que você se refere a class da linha da tabela `<td class="ModeloEquipamentoID" ` correto ? Então ficaria desse jeito ? `$(this).find('td:ModeloEquipamentoID(1)').text()`;

Comment: Não amigo, a pseudo classe faz referência a uma ordem, então, a sua primeira TD, será a nth-child(1), a segunda TD nth-child(2) e assim por diante. Lembre-se que a pseudo classe está fazendo referência as TDs filhas da TR que está na iteração do looping

Comment: Muito bem! adicionei o código pra criar o objeto `dados[i] = new Object()`, porém tem um problema: o código tá trazendo uma linha vazia a mais que é o cabeçalho, como faço pra não adicionar no array dados[] a primeira linha (header) da tabela ?

Comment: Se você estiver separando a tabela com <thead> e <tbody>, você pode usar assim: $('#tblContato > tbody');.
Se você não estiver usando thead e tbody, você pode filtrar as TRs descartando a primeira linha, desta forma:  table.find('tr').not( ':first' ).each(...

Comment: obrigado!,  funcionou.

Comment: Disponha amigo!!